# Partition suddenly not accessible

Tags: linux, ntfs, linux-mint

Okay, so I was working on my system, nothing fancy (and most definitely nothing that would have any reason to cause this issue) when I suddenly saw my primary data partition disappear from the list of mounted partitions so I decided to run GParted to see if it could tell me why

```
Unable to find mount point 
Unable to read the contents of this file
system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable
```

So I thought "that's odd" and decided that GParted is of no use this time so I run a few commands in the terminal to see if I can resolve it

```
zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for zero: 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="20820BC1820B9A84" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="8CE22AC7E22AB4FC" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="eeb8ea7f-7507-4b4c-9a4d-b75a871b7aba" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="2E652F573B232F6D" TYPE="ntfs" 
zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ sudo umount /dev/sda4
umount: /media/2E652F573B232F6D: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ lsof /dev/sda4
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuseblk file system /media/2E652F573B232F6D
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

So to quickly recap my intent: check if the UUID is correct, it is.
Okay, then I shall unmount and remount it... yeah, didn't work.

then I try this

```
zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ sudo parted /dev/sda4 unit s print
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sda4: 385789952s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End         Size        File system  Flags
 1      0s     385789951s  385789952s  ntfs

zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ sudo fdisk -l -u

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8028af30

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    51406847    25600000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        51406848   102606847    25600000   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       102606848   488396799   192894976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK2576GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 488397168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start       End         Size        Type     File system  Flags
 1      2048s       206847s     204800s     primary  ntfs         boot
 2      206848s     51406847s   51200000s   primary  ntfs
 3      51406848s   102606847s  51200000s   primary  ext4
 4      102606848s  488396799s  385789952s  primary  ntfs

zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=738214,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=592156k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/eeb8ea7f-7507-4b4c-9a4d-b75a871b7aba / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1184300k 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /dev/cgroup/cpu cgroup rw,relatime,cpu,release_agent=/usr/local/sbin/cgroup_clean 0 0
/dev/sda4 /media/2E652F573B232F6D fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ cat /etc/mtab
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=738214,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=592156k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/eeb8ea7f-7507-4b4c-9a4d-b75a871b7aba / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1184300k 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /dev/cgroup/cpu cgroup rw,relatime,cpu,release_agent=/usr/local/sbin/cgroup_clean 0 0
/dev/sda4 /media/2E652F573B232F6D fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
zero@hhs-dev9 ~ $ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc    /proc   proc    defaults    0   0
# /dev/sda3
UUID=eeb8ea7f-7507-4b4c-9a4d-b75a871b7aba   /   ext4    rw,errors=remount-ro    0   1
```

And the partition is clearly found in /proc/mounts and in /etc/mtab with a correct UUID, and I am at loss, I cannot for my life figure out why it suddenly stopped working and why I can't unmount and remount it

Comment: Did you look in syslog's logs ? Like a corruption of the SATA/SAS/SCSI driver ?

Comment: I did, I managed to "solve" it by booting into an arch-linux live usb (any other one would've worked, I just happened to find it first) and I did a binary copy, formated the partition as btrfs (I don't have any need for a shared drive anymore so it doesn't matter) and copied all the files from the binary copy. to the new btrfs system which could be mounted properly.
Still not sure why that specific partition can't be mounted on my system when other ntfs partitions work fine.